# Custom Tooltip in Google Sheets Org Chart

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-query

I am trying to find a way to make a custom tooltip under Org Chart built using the Google Sheets.

Currently, I have an Org chart that is built by simply selecting the data on the sheet and inserting the chart through the menu. I have recently learned that it is possible to have a custom tooltip (see an [example here][1][1]: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#tooltip-actions)

My data is currently under 3 columns. I am unable to figure out how to call the data from the sheet to draw the org chart with custom tooltips.

I would like to keep the ability to update the chart dynamically whenever the data is changed/added/removed from the sheet.

Can someone please help me with this.

Best Regards,
Syed H

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the property tooltip to true in the option

```
var options = {
   tooltip: {isHtml: true},
   legend: 'none'
};
```

then you can add tooltip in the AddColumns and you just have to pass the content tooltip in add Row

```
function drawChart() {
   var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Year');
   dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
   // A column for custom tooltip content
   dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
   dataTable.addRows([
      ['2010', 600,'First Tooltip'],
      ['2011', 1500, 'Second Tooltip'],
      ['2012', 800, 'Third Tooltip'],
      ['2013', 1000, '$1M in sales last year.']
]);
```

Here is a JSFiddle Example for Bar chart: https://jsfiddle.net/foufrix/qfcps6vu/3/

And here is for Org Chart : https://jsfiddle.net/foufrix/z3fvm9p1/2/

Custom Tooltip for org Chart using css : https://jsfiddle.net/z3fvm9p1/7/
Implementation of W3S code : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

If you have dynamique Data you can listen to it and everytime it changes you can relaunch the function drawChart

Comment: Foufrix, thank you for your response. I do not want to add data through the function, rather would like to pick the data from the existing sheet. This way, I would like to keep the ability to dynamically update the chart. I would also like to use the Org chart and not the column chart. Please help. Best Regars, Syed H

Comment: For the existing sheet save the data you want to pass and reuse it. The code i've wrote is just an example from the docs you provided, you can change it to make it in org chart.
By the way, tooltip are available for : AreaChart
BarChart
CalendarChart
CandlestickChart
ColumnChart
ComboChart
LineChart
PieChart
Sankey Diagrams
ScatterChart
Timeline, considering the google chart docs.
It means that for org chart there is no simple way provided by google chart to use tooltip.

Comment: After reading the google docs, you have everything on the google org charts docs, you have to put value in the third element of the arrays in addRow

Here is an example from google doc : https://jsfiddle.net/foufrix/z3fvm9p1/2/ @SyedHussaini

Comment: Dear Foufrix, thank you for taking time and adding your helpful inputs. I have already built the Org Chart with tooltips, however, I need to know how I can add some custom style to the tooltips and also make them stay as show in this particular sample [example here][1][1]: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#tooltip-actions). I am unable to figure ways to add the existing data by calling them into the draw function. please help

Comment: @SyedHussaini Here you go : https://jsfiddle.net/z3fvm9p1/5/
You can add custom html in your array, i defined a custome tooltip style in css and used a function to add the text you want and the tooltip you want.
There is an example on how you can use custom data (const datasheets1)
Keep me informed, and don't forget to validate if the answer helped you ;)