# Need Tooltips: Change google sheet existing data into DataTable

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

**Problem:**
All the documentation I see uses a DataTable that writes the data in the script itself. I need to call this tooltip data from existing rows.
I need to understand the code difference between an HTML page and an embedded chart in a google sheet.

**Goal:**
I have a scatter plot that needs custom tooltips. I need the data from column Q to show as the tooltip, on hover with the data in column R and S
insert chart using this code plus tooltip:

```
    function newChart() {
  // Generate a chart representing the data in the range of A1:B15.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[11];

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCATTER)
     .addRange(sheet.getRange('R3:S5000'))
     .addRange(sheet.getRange('Q3:Q5000'))

     .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
     .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

-OR-

```
 function drawChart() {
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        // A column for custom tooltip content
        dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
        dataTable.addRows([
          ['2010', 600,'$600K in our first year!'],
          ['2011', 1500, 'Sunspot activity made this our best year ever!'],
          ['2012', 800, '$800K in 2012.'],
          ['2013', 1000, '$1M in sales last year.']
        ]);

        var options = {
          tooltip: {isHtml: true},
          legend: 'none'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('col_chart_html_tooltip'));
        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
      }
```

references:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#tooltip-actions
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets

Comment: Here's a similar question that may be relevant. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186112/custom-tooltip-in-google-sheets-org-chart)

Answer (score 1):

in the embedded chart, use a data view definition to add the tooltip role...

see following snippet...

```
function newChart() {
  // Generate a chart representing the data in the range of A1:B15.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[11];

  // build the data view definition
  var COLUMN_SPEC = [
    0,
    1,
    {sourceColumn: 2, role: 'tooltip'}
  ];
  var viewSpec = Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
     .setColumns(COLUMN_SPEC)
     .build();

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCATTER)
     .setDataViewDefinition(viewSpec)
     .addRange(sheet.getRange('R3:S5000'))
     .addRange(sheet.getRange('Q3:Q5000'))

     .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
     .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Comment: So, @whitehat where would I enter my tooltip column (Q3:5000) ?  **Thanks!**

Comment: I get this error:
_TypeError: Cannot find function setDataViewDefinition in object EmbeddedChartBuilder._ @WhiteHat

Comment: So in hoping to use your setDataViewDefinition, I found https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/scatter-chart-builder using Scatterplot chart. I am also so frustrated with all the docs showing UiApp in all their examples. It makes it so hard when it's mixed with depreciated stuff.
Then, how can I take the example on that page to work with HTML service like 
 https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html ? @WhiteHat

Comment: I see that your answer does not work.  I listed the error above, as well as my new plan using your setDataViewDefinition without EmbeddedChartBuilder. Do you have any clarification or any paths to help me figure it out myself? thx @whitehat