# TypeError: sheet.newChart(...).setChartType(...).setDataViewDefinition is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to draw a chart with Google Apps Script in Google Sheets. I have a spreadsheet and a file called Code.gs.

```
function newChart() {
  // Generate a chart representing the data in the range of A1:B15.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // build the data view definition
  var COLUMN_SPEC = [
    0,
    1,
    {sourceColumn: 2, role: 'tooltip'}
  ];
  var viewSpec = Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
     .setColumns(COLUMN_SPEC)
     .build();

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
     .setDataViewDefinition(viewSpec)
     .addRange(sheet.getRange('A2:B20'))
     .addRange(sheet.getRange('C2:C20'))

     .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
     .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

I get the following error when running the function newChart():

```
TypeError: sheet.newChart(...).setChartType(...).setDataViewDefinition is not a function (line 18, file "Code")
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

**References:**

[Need Tooltips: Change google sheet existing data into DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605363/need-tooltips-change-google-sheet-existing-data-into-datatable)

Comment: See [official documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for embedded sheet reference.

Comment: I did, take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-view-definition-builder). It uses the method setDataViewDefinition on sheet.newChart().

Comment: That's not ``EmbeddedChart`` class. It's ``Charts`` class. They are different classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `sheet.newChart()` does not have the method `.setDataViewDefinition()`.

You can either skip it:

```
function newChart() {
  // Generate a chart representing the data in the range of A1:B15.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // build the data view definition
  var COLUMN_SPEC = [
    0,
    1,
    {sourceColumn: 2, role: 'tooltip'}
  ];
  var viewSpec = Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
     .setColumns(COLUMN_SPEC)
     .build();

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
     .addRange(sheet.getRange('A2:B20'))
     .addRange(sheet.getRange('C2:C20'))

     .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
     .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

or use it with the `Charts.newTableChart()` object. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-view-definition-builder) for example.

Comment: Ok, but why does Google use it in their documentation then? See link in comment above. Is it an error in their documentation?

Comment: I guess it has been deprecated.